# Stored procedures in Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I have this requirement to recreate the stored procedures of SQL Server in Python. The flow involves one stored procedure say 'sp_main' begins execution and in its execution calls a number of other stored procedures.

What I wanted to know exactly was to know what fares better? Functions inside a single script or multiple scripts for all the different stored procedures I am trying to create.

EDIT 2: Created functions instead of different scripts and found that it was better than calling individual scripts from inside the main python file. This didn't require me making a new connection for every file. Thank you @Rahul Neekhra for helping me out.

EDIT1 : I have already started to create different scripts for each of the store procedures but this is requiring me to make connection each and every time the call is made to another script.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it depends on the requirement. But the best way is to call sp_main once and call all other stored proc inside that.

Reasons why

1. You will many calls fro python to sql server.
2. You will many connection to perform one task with multiple calls.
3. easy to handle\manage when changes will require in any of the procedure logic. This will save deployment of python.
4. If transactions are included to sub calls you can manage from 'sp_main'
5. Procedures are pre-complied objects so you will get the performance advantage as well.

I am not aware about python but working on SQL server since long time so I prefer more doing with SQL rather front end code more frequently.

Comment: Thanks. That is the way it is in SQL Server but in Python I have to write all the stored procedures again. So I didn't know what to do about that

Comment: do you want to recreated everything in python which is written in sql server?

Comment: Yes. The stored procedures won't exist in SQL Server anymore

Comment: Even in that case you can follow same approach. Some of the advantages you won't get it but of course manageability will be at ease of doing level.